# Convert all the integer value to string in JSON

Tags: java, json

My JSON string is:

```
{name:"MyNode", width:200, height:100}
```

I want to change it to:

```
{name:"MyNode", width:"200", height:"100"}
```

so that all integer values become strings

---

My main code is:

```
{
     "firstName": "John",
     "lastName": "Smith",
     "age": 25,
     "address":
     {
         "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
         "city": "New York",
         "state": "NY",
         "xy": 10021
     },
     "IDNumber":
     [
         {
           "type": "home",
           "number": 1234
         },
         {
           "type": "fax",
           "number": 4567
         }
     ]
 }
```

I need all integer values become strings

Comment: -1 for unanswerable question since you're not saying which programming language you are using.

Comment: @Matt Ball: I tagged the question with [javascript]. No language was specified but the post contained JS object literals (not JSON, as you pointed out in your answer).  So I removed the [json] tag and replaced it with [javascript].

Comment: @Andy d'oh didn't look far back enough in the edit history, thank'ya

Answer (score 10):

That's a JavaScript object literal, not JSON. Anyway...

```
var obj = {name:"MyNode", width:200, height:100};

for (var k in obj)
{
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k))
    {
        obj[k] = String(obj[k]);
    }
}

// obj = {name:"MyNode", width: "200", height: "100"}
```

If you're actually working with JSON, not an object, [`JSON.parse()`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js#L103) the string beforehand, and [`JSON.stringify()`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js#L22) the object afterward.

Comment: actually i got the json value in my java code. so i have to do work in java only.

Comment: @user: that's the kind of thing you need to mention when you ask your question, rather than after you get answers.

Comment: @Matt Ball, just curious, why do you have the `obj.hasOwnProperty` check? Since you're iterating over the object's properties, normally you already know that the object has this property, or am I missing something?

Comment: @user are you using any JSON libraries? If not, check out [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Comment: @Laurent `Object.hasOwnProperty()` makes sure that you ignore unwanted properties from the object's prototype. See the note in yellow: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Parameters

Answer (score 6):

If you must operate on the JSON string :

```
json = json.replace (/:(\d+)([,\}])/g, ':"$1"$2');
```

Comment: i am using json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar. There is no replace method in that jar. can we do the same thing in java. if can please suggest.

Comment: This was a very helpful answer. The reason to do this is if you have really large numbers (>53 bits of precision), then when you `JSON.parse` them, you lose precision. When you're using them as an ID, that's really bad. For my situation, since I never do math on them, I can treat them as strings and everything is great.  Here's the function I used: `json.replace (/:\s*(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d+)\s*([,\}])/g, ':"$1"$2');`. It has the advantage of only doing the replace on really big numbers, and it deals with spaces after the colon and before the comma or brace.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
const stringifyNumbers = obj => {                                                                                      
  const result = {};                                                                                                   
  Object.entries(obj).map(entry => {                                                                                   
    const type = typeof entry[1];                                                                                      
    if (Array.isArray(entry[1])) {                                                                                     
      result[entry[0]] = entry[1].map(entry => stringifyNumbers(entry));                                               
    } else if (type === 'object' && !!entry[1]) {                                                                      
      result[entry[0]] = stringifyNumbers(entry[1]);                                                                   
    } else if (entry[1] === null) {                                                                                    
      result[entry[0]] = null;                                                                                         
    } else if (type === 'number') {                                                                                    
      result[entry[0]] = String(entry[1]);                                                                             
    } else {                                                                                                           
      result[entry[0]] = entry[1];                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                  
  });                                                                                                                  
  return result;                                                                                                       
}
```

most ids should be strings in my opinion. If your api cannot provide ids as strings this snippet will convert them.