# Problem parse integer within JSON response

Tags: java, json

How to convert number values in json string to string format.
such as

```
100 - "100"
```

i am getting the result from response and set to a string (in java).

anybody suggest the right way

my whole string is

```
{name:"MyNode", width:200, height:100, my:[1,2,"ambika"]}
```

i need the result should be

```
{name:"MyNode", width:"200", height:"100", my:["1","2","ambika"]}
```

Comment: If you are doing it in Java, you must assign the Java tag, otherwise Java people may miss your question.

Comment: Are you trying to convert a number format to a string so that you can do string concatenation rather than addition, or vice versa? I ask because in your example, you're doing subtraction, which isn't a valid string operation, but in your description you say "how to convert number values in json string to string format."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert all the integer value to string in JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389598/convert-all-the-integer-value-to-string-in-json)

Answer (score 0):

You can do `100 - parseInt("100")` or `100 - +"100"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something that want to load in into an JSON-like object. However, the above is not a valid JSON object but fortunately a YAML object, which is a superset of a JSON object.

You can use YAML library for Java to load your string into YAML object, and use it just like JSON object in your implementation.

[JYaml](http://jyaml.sourceforge.net/)

```
Yaml temp = new Yaml();
temp.load({name:"MyNode", width:200, height:100, my:[1,2,"ambika"]});
```

You can then use temp to extract the value using keys,etc. Just looking for the JavaDocs they provided