# Replace long integers in raw json with strings

Tags: c#, regex, json

I'm looking for a way to wrap all integers over 17 digits long in a json-formatted string in quotes (essentially making them strings when deserialized).

Someone facing the same issue in Javascript posted here [Convert all the integer value to string in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389598/convert-all-the-integer-value-to-string-in-json)

I suspect there is a way to use Regex.Replace() here but the need to understand the syntax and regex's between the two languages has me a bit lost.

So far I have:

```
        string pattern =  @"/:\s*(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d+)\s*([,\}])/g";
        content = Regex.Replace(content,pattern, @":""{1}""{2}");
```

Comment: Heres some example data :

 `[ { "blingCompoundKey": { "id": 4510887396879241700, "dateTime": 1434087934451 }, "name": "Candy 5", "description": "" }, { "blingCompoundKey": { "id": 8351288136120734000, "dateTime": 1434267982997 }, "name": "test", "description": "" }]`

and I've started testing the regex component here separately as its a bit easier for a beginner https://regex101.com/

Comment: Can this be fixed on the server side?

Comment: It could (and really should) be, given how often Javascript will end up handling REST output and mangling the integers. For now this will allow development on the front end to continue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zero-width negative lookahead/lookbehind (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#grouping_constructs) is what you should be using to make sure there are no quotes at the start or end. That way you don't need to know about the exact JSON format when you do the replacement:

```
string pattern = @"(?<![""\w])(\d{17,})(?![""\w])";
string content = Regex.Replace(content, pattern, "\"$1\"");
```

This solution won't care whether there is a space between the `:` and the number. It will also handle numbers in arrays `[ 0123456701234567,  0123456701234567 ]` or by themselves.

Regex still isn't an ideal solution unless you know what content will be passed into it as this breaks as soon as you have a number included in a string value, e.g. `"abc 0123456701234567 def"`.

Comment: Great, I also added a check that will allow negative numbers, which I hope doesnt introduce any new uncertainties  `(?<![""\w])(-?\d{17,})(?![""\w])` . This is definitely not a long term solution for anyone, as you said - just a patch for some well-defined test data until my backend can send ids as strings properly.

Comment: This is a good solution - but is there a reason you have the double-quote character twice in each character group (`[""\w]`)?

Comment: Also `\w` includes numeric characters, so I think your look-ahead and look-behind subexpressions should be `["\D]` (don't match against double-quote or any non-numeric digit)

Comment: The double-quote is for escaping - because regular expressions tend to use a lot of backslashes I prefer `@"..."`. The lookahead and lookbehind are **negative** so it won't match `abc01234678901234567def`.

Answer (score 0):

> wrap all integers over 17 digits long in a json-formatted string in quotes

I would use the following:

```
string pattern =  "[^\"\\d](\\d{17,})[^\"\\d]";
content = Regex.Replace(content,pattern, "\"$1\"");
```

The first line selects all numeric values of 17 digits or greater (and ensure that they aren't already strings). 
The second line wraps these 17 digits inside of double quotes.

If your JSON is minified, it changes the regex a little. We can use, which will make sure the resulting JSON is still valid.

```
string pattern =  ":(\\d{17,})";
content = Regex.Replace(content,pattern, "\"$1\"");
```

Comment: I had to rejig some of the escaped quotes in your example to the below:  `string pattern =  @"[^""\d](\d{17,})[^""\d]";
content = Regex.Replace(content,pattern, @"$1");` but it seems to replace a character either side (in this case it removes a : and , as the json has no whitespace). Any idea if this is the original regex, or something I changed in the substitution by adding double quotes?

Comment: my mistake - the characters being deleted was a simplified version of your regex (any 17+digit number) I was using as the original didn't match any values and I wanted to see it matching. I'll add some sample data in case that illustrates the issue

Comment: I used your sample data, and here's an example of it matching: https://regex101.com/r/oF6rC6/1 With .net, I would remove the `@` symbol in front of the string, and just use double backquotes as in my last updated answer.

Comment: Fantastic, I bamboozled myself with the various escape characters- removing the @ works. The output I now get is `{"blingCompoundKey":{"id""4510887396879241701""dateTime":1434087934451},` . I think the regex arguments that are looking 1 character either side for potential quotes are also counted as part of the replace target. It works without those however -  I may have to settle for not being sensitive to already-quoted long integers for now.

Comment: OK it looks like you are working on minified JSON (no spaces between key/values). In that case the pattern could be something like `":(\\d{17,})"`